# React Component won't work in a dynamic way when passed different prop values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a File Upload Component in React using the code from Material UI as shown in the example given here - https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Now, I have made a couple of modifications to enable to reuse the file upload in different components for different file types, and I have used a conditional operator to allow me display the component for those different file types.

Unfortunately, I am hitting a couple of problems and I have tried different ways to fix it:

- I have the component displayed twice in a parent component but used for different file types by passing either ".txt" or ".csv". When the component used with .txt the dialog only shows .txt files, but when the component is used for .csv, the dialog does get set again to the correct file type.
- Equally, I am not able to load the .csv file when the component is used for this type. For simplicity I am not doing anything with the file except to grab the file name. I can do this with .txt files, but not the other.

I have console.log on the load of the component each time to ensure that the correct file extension is being passed in and it is each time the component is loaded (props.fileType) and this is then being used in conditional operator on the return. I know the return is working as I have different display text showing for each file extension. Input accept attribute is set hard coded as either ".csv" or ".txt".

So, my question, how do you set the file upload to ensure that it works as intended?

Relevant Code Below-

THIS IS HOW THE PARENT IS LAYED OUT -

```
            <ListItemIcon>

            <PublishIcon fontSize="small" className={classes.iconStyle}    />

          </ListItemIcon>

          <ListItemText primary={"Upload File"} aria-hidden={true} />

        </ListItem>

          <Upload fileType={".txt"}/>  

          <ListItemIcon>

            <AttachmentIcon fontSize="small" className={classes.iconStyle} />

          </ListItemIcon>

          <ListItemText primary={"Attach a Document"} aria-hidden={true} />

        </ListItem>

          <Upload fileType={".csv"}/>
```

THIS IS THE ACTUAL UPLOAD COMPONENT ITSELF
const UploadButton = props => {

```
const classes = useStyles(); 

const [selectedFileCsv, setSelectedFileCsv]= useState(null); 

const [selectedFileTxt, setSelectedFileTxt]= useState(null); 


let fileCsv;

let fileTxt;



if(props.fileType===".csv")

{

 fileCsv = props.fileType;

 console.log(fileCsv);

}

else

{

  fileTxt = props.fileType;

  console.log(filePdf);

}



  const handleselectedFileCSV=(e)=>{ 

       setSelectedFileCsv(e.target.files[0].name) 

   }

  const handleselectedFileTXT=(e)=>{ 


     setSelectedFileTxt(e.target.files[0].name);



  }



return ( 

    <div className={classes.root}> 

      { filetxt ?

       <React.Fragment>

        <input 

          accept=".txt"

          className={classes.input} 

          id="contained-button-file" 

          type="file" 

          onChange={handleselectedFileTXT} 

          /> 

          <label htmlFor="contained-button-file"> 

              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span"> 

                  Upload

              </Button> 

              

          </label>

            <input  

                accept=".txt" 

                className={classes.input}  

                id="icon-button-file"  

            /> 

            <label htmlFor="icon-button-file" value={selectedFileTXT}> 

                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span"> 

                </IconButton> 

            </label> 

            <p>Filename: {selectedFileTXT}</p>

            <p>File Type: {fileTxt}</p>

         </React.Fragment>

        :

        <React.Fragment>

        <input 

          accept=".csv"

          className={classes.input} 

          id="contained-button-file" 

          type="file" 

          onChange={handleselectedFileCSV} 

          /> 

         <label htmlFor="contained-button-file"> 

              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span"> 

                  Attach File

              </Button> 

              

          </label>

            <input  

                accept=".csv" 

                className={classes.input}  

                id="icon-button-file"  

            /> 

         <label htmlFor="icon-button-file" value={selectedFileCSV}> 

            <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span"> 

                </IconButton> 

            </label> 

            <p>Filename: {selectedFileCSV}</p>

            <p>File Type: {fileCsv}</p>

            </React.Fragment>

}

        </div>

                

     );

   }
```

I have tried different things such as browsers, thinking it might be an environmental thing, and the situation is the same. Further, I have tried breaking the code out to different components one for text files and one for CSV files, and what I found was very similar. The dialog never updated, and the filename for the csv file updated the filename variable in the txt file rather than itself. Even the variable names were different and the components were independent.

Comment: Could you share a working example showing this problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - code added along with extra information

Answer (score 0):

Silly me - all I had to do was to rename the ids to the input tags for the other file type such as add txt or csv and the problem goes away